# I Need to help to move an image across the screen

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

i am making a game, the image which i took from my pc is not moving on the screen, is something wrong please help me

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player extends Entity{    
    int velX=0,velY=0, speed =5;

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public void Update(){       
        y+=velY;
        x+=velX;
        checkCollision();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImage(),x,y, null);
        g2d.draw(getbounds());
    }

    public Image getPlayerImage(){
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("D:/abc.png");
        return ic.getImage();       
    }

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key== KeyEvent.VK_UP) velY=-speed;       
        else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) velY=speed;
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) velX-=speed;
        else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) velX=speed;
        else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) GameFrame.addMissile(new Missile(x,y));
    }

    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key== KeyEvent.VK_UP)velY=0;
        else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) velY=0;
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) velX=0;
        else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) velX=0;
    }

    public void checkCollision(){
        ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = GameFrame.getEnemyList();        
        for(int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
            Enemy tempEnemy = enemies.get(i);
            if(getbounds().intersects(enemies.get(i).getbounds())) System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getbounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x,y,getPlayerImage().getWidth(null),getPlayerImage().getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

there is another 7 classes but the image moving work is here and also a KeyAdapt class who just working as a keyadapter

Comment: No movements are working at all?

Comment: In your VK_UP, you have this `velY =- speed;`. You sure it shouldn't be `velY += speed;`?

Comment: Why AWT and not Swing? Please consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Swing is a much more robust and powerful GUI library, and there really should be no reason to use the far older and weaker AWT library. Also you'll find **many** examples of just this sort of thing -- moving a sprite via key press -- with Swing in answers on this site, than you will with AWT. Do yourself a favor and just switch.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I dont think that really helps and when you give advice to switch to a better language for UI's then i think swing is a bad choice, considering that you can do alot more and better with C++, Qt for example. Better performance, no VM, etc ...

Comment: @fonZ: I am **not** giving advice to use a "better" language. I'm recommending a **better library**. Please re-read my suggestion. There are two GUI libraries commonly used for building Java GUI's, AWT, and Swing which superseded AWT in 1999 -- 13 years ago. If someone desires to create a Java GUI, they should never use AWT. Period.

Comment: Library is wat i wanted to say but basically it comes down to the same point, you have to rewrite your code, partly or completely. And then C++ is a better choice as there are libraries that extend the language and give all the advantages you have in java plus all the benefits. So to come to my point, you were giving advice by telling not to use obselete **libraries**.

Comment: @fonZ: `" ... you were giving advice by telling not to use obselete libraries."` -- and so shame on me. I'll try not to give such advice in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at when you press the mouse, you want to move but it depends if you move left or right you should decrease or increase. Same with up or down.

So when you go up and down you move along the Y axis that starts with 0 north (up) and ends with maximum value of Y south (down) So if you want to move up you do velY -= speed and if you want to go down you do velY += speed. Assuming velY is 0 at that time and speed is greater then 0.

The same goes for the X axis, left is 0 and right is the maximum value of X. When you go left you decrease from 0 (velX: -5) and increase from 0 when you go right (velX: +5).

Another thing is that when you need your ImageIcon multiple times it's always better to make it a private attribute because that way it's only instantiated once. That will improve your performance alot because every time you instantiate an ImageIcon with an image that is sitting on the hard drive then you have disk-IO operations which slow down everything.

Naming is also important in Java, you write method names with capital letters which is not correct. Method names should start with small letters and use camelcase.

I rewrote your code with a switch case statement to make it more readable.

```
public class Player extends Entity {    
    private int velX=0,velY=0, speed =5;
    private ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("D:/abc.png");

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(){       
        y+=velY;
        x+=velX;
        checkCollision();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImage(),x,y, null);
        g2d.draw(getbounds());
    }

    public Image getPlayerImage(){
        return ic.getImage();       
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:    velY -= speed; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:  velY += speed; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:  velX -= speed; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: velX += speed; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: GameFrame.addMissile(new Missile(x,y)); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:    velY = 0; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:  velY = 0; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:  velX = 0; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: velX = 0; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    public void checkCollision(){
        ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = GameFrame.getEnemyList();        
        for(int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
            Enemy tempEnemy = enemies.get(i);
            if(getbounds().intersects(enemies.get(i).getbounds())) System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getbounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x,y,getPlayerImage().getWidth(null),getPlayerImage().getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception error,, can you please give me your fb link then i will send you my whole project,,

Comment: basically, i didn't understand the logic which you implemented here

Comment: The image is not moving yet,,, :(

Comment: There can be multiple reasons, 1. you should check if the mouse is reacting and 2. if the update method is being called somewhere.